# Sybase IQ datepart function strange behaviour

Tags: sql, database, sybase, datepart, iq

I am facing an issue in Sybase IQ running datepart function which is supposed to return the value of 1 for **2024-01-28**, but it returns 7 instead. My **char_date** column is stored as *varchar(10)* in the database.

Here are two queries to compare. When I run it on real table data, it returns 7 for the column datep, however for constant varchar(10), it returns the right value (1):

```
-- 1
SELECT char_date , datepart(dw,  cast(char_date AS date)) as datep
FROM MyTable

-- 2
SELECT '20240128' char_date , datepart(dw,  cast('20240128' AS date)) as datep
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: fly-on-the-wall question: what is returned by the queries `select cast(char_date AS date), cast('20240128' AS date) from MyTable` and `select 'true' from MyTable where cast(char_date AS date) = cast('20240128' AS date)`

Comment: Hello, it returns true